# The spreadsheet doesn't show you any information

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image]

I made a curve.
On the geometry node, if I control the 0th instance, it's controlled.
But I don't see any information on the spreadsheet
I tried to click the original, evaluate, but it didn't work.
I tried pressing the filter on the upper right, but it didn't work.
Why isn't there anything on the spreadsheet?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to add a "viewer node" in your node tree? 
It is this node that allow you to see info in the spreadsheet

Comment: I tried, but I don't think it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my previous comment, you need to add a viewer node to your geometry nodes tree.

Spreadsheet is used to inspect geometry attributes.

Your current tree (at the end, before the group output) is displaying two instances, two cubes. So you need to check it under the "instances" data set region of the spreadsheet viewer, like the screenshot below.

More info about the spreadsheet here :
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/spreadsheet.html

[image: Viewer Node - Spreadsheet]

Comment: I have to select the viewer node. Thank you for kindly letting me know by attaching a screenshot.

Comment: The view node means it is in the upper left corner of the left.